# Finding a duplicate numbers in an array and then counting the number of duplicates

Tags: ios, nsarray

How would I take an array with long list of numbers that contains duplicates, so for instance:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"45", @"60", @"100",@"100", @"100", @"60"nil];
```

Just imagine that this is a HUGE list of random numbers. Now I'm sure that I have to use something like NSSet for this, but i'm not sure how to execute this. Also, once we identify the duplicates I'm guessing that I would then add those numbers to an array, and then call

```
[array count];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use double for loops.

Comment: What exactly do you want to count? The total removed?

Comment: `NSOrderedSet` or `NSCountedSet`, depending on what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];

int duplicates = 0;
for (id object in set) {
  if ([set countForObject:object] > 1) {
    duplicates++;
  }
}
```

This will calculate how many elements have a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

A sidenote, that array contains a bunch of strings, no numbers...

Anyway, if the goal is to get just the count you could use the following single line to get it.

```
NSUInteger diff = [array count] - [[array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"] count];
```

This uses KVC (Key-Value Coding) to get all distinct objects (that is ones without a dupe) counts them and gets the difference from the original count.

Comment: This is a very useful technique, but note that it won't actually tell you how many items have a duplicate, since a given element may have many duplicates (and so would be overcounted here).

Comment: Yes, hence why I added the comment about the goal, if the goal is to eliminate the dupes, then the KVC itself is enough, but indeed if the goal is to get number of elements with >= 1 dupe, then this approach is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

`NSCountedSet` is perfect for what you want to do.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"45", @"60", @"100",@"100", @"100", @"60",nil];
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:array];
__block NSUInteger totalNumberOfDuplicates = 0;
[countedSet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSUInteger duplicateCountForObject = [countedSet countForObject:obj];
    if (duplicateCountForObject > 1)
        totalNumberOfDuplicates += duplicateCountForObject;
    NSLog(@"%@ appears %ld times", obj, duplicateCountForObject);
}];

NSLog(@"Total number of duplicates is %ld", totalNumberOfDuplicates);
```

produces:

```
45 appears 1 times
60 appears 2 times
100 appears 3 times
Total number of duplicates is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` this use a predicate with your condition and return an array with the objects you need.

```
NSArray* arr=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"10",@"11",@"10",@"2", nil];

    NSLog(@"%d",[[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == '2'"]] count]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SELF >= '2'`?

Comment: First, why are you making a `Mutable` array? Second, and related, use the new syntax, `@[@"10",...]`. Third, this has nothing to do with duplicates, which is what the question is about.

Comment: Sorry, I already fixed the 'Mutable' line.

This can return a specific value count in the array, if you change '2' for '10', the result must be an array with count = 2